# Stick date to the top until a new dates appears during scroll like in WhatsApp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do the same with the date like WhatsApp does on mobile and web when you start scrolling. Heres a question about this topic but only in Android but I want to do this in HTML, CSS and JS:

[How to display a date like Whatsapp on scrolling ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397127/how-to-display-a-date-like-whatsapp-on-scrolling-listview)

So this is my actual layout I have:

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#messages > div { 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.message.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.divider {
 text-align: center;
}

.divider span {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="divider">
    <span>22.02.2020</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="divider">
    <span>Heute</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
</div>
```

Is there any possible way to detect when a date (22.02.2020 or Heute) scrolls out of the view with a bit of space from the top? If yes, how can I stick this at the top of my scrolling border box until the next date comes in?

**UPDATE**

Here you can see what I mean:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @anroesti Nothing because I have 0 idea how to do this. This is too complex for my skills at the moment :) But thanks for asking! Sometimes I forgot to add what I've tried.

Comment: Pure CSS has `position: fixed`. As you only want it to be fixed once it is outside of the viewport, you will probably need JavaScript. A place to start would be to listen on the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) and get the dividers position in the viewport using [`getClientBoundingRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), then set the dividers `position: fixed` once this function tells you it is outside of the viewport after a scroll.

Comment: @anroesti Thanks for the hint. I'v checked out WhatApp Web and it looks like they are cloning the dates somehow when they reach a specific top bit thats all I can figure out at the moment.

Comment: In that case they might clone it in order for it to still take up space. If you take an element in the document and then set it to fixed, the content below it will move up. The main part of detecting if something is out of the viewport and then setting it to a fixed position should be possible using the linked resouces. Maybe there is also something in jQuery UI or some other framework that already implements this if you don't want to build your own from scratch.

Comment: @anroesti Sounds interesting. Do you know any framework? Or is this just an idea.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a way too complex for Stackoverflow. I'll try to find someone who can help me with this. When I got this done, I'll share my answer here. If someone wants to try it, I also would love to see the answer because I'm not sure how long this will take until I get this - somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a JS solution to give you an idea of how you might do it with JS:

```js
const topLabel = document.getElementById('date-label')
const messageBox = document.getElementById('messages')
messageBox.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const dateLabels = document.querySelectorAll('.divider')
  let currentLabel = null
  dateLabels.forEach((dateLabel) => {
    if(messageBox.scrollTop >= dateLabel.offsetTop)
    {
      currentLabel = dateLabel
    }
  })
  if(currentLabel) {
    topLabel.style.opacity = '1'
    topLabel.innerText = currentLabel.innerText
  } else {
    topLabel.style.opacity = '0'
  }
})
```

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

#messages > div { 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.message.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.divider {
  text-align: center;
}

.divider span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages">
  <div class="divider sticky">
    <span id="date-label" style="opacity: 0;">22.02.2020</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="divider">
    <span>22.02.2020</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="divider">
    <span>Heute</span>
  </div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mr.Jo, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS's `position: sticky;` You'll need to enclose each dated group of messages in its own div. Below I have enclosed the dated groups in a div with `class="date-area"`, just to identify them. I have only applied styles to `.divider`. You can see I added `position: sticky;` and `top: 10px` to stick the date ten pixels from the top of the viewport as you scroll:

**Edit:**
I've added `.spacer` divs at the bottom of the date groups, then offset the date labels toward the top by the same height as the spacers. This way the date labels overlap completely to give the feeling of 'replacing' the date. I can't see any benefit to cloning the date label as WhatsApp does. The only way I can think of to fully mimic that behavior is by using JS, and I don't consider it to be good practice to use JS for purely presentation purposes unless there is some tangible benefit. Where's the benefit in completely duplicating WhatsApp's design?

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#messages > div { 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.message.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.divider {
  text-align: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.divider span {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.date-area {
  margin-top: -35px;
}

.spacer {
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages">
  <div class="date-area">
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="date-area">
    <div class="divider">
      <span>22.02.2020</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="date-area">
    <div class="divider">
      <span>Heute</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
    <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, this is the sticky way! Maybe do you have an idea how to handle it with cloning like in WhatApp? Do you have WhatsApp? Otherwise I can add a GIF if you want

Comment: No. I don't have WhatsApp. A GIF would help. Thanks!

Comment: I've finally got it making a GIF of my idea. Check out my answer if you like.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it slightly more similar to the GIF by allowing the date labels to overlap. However, the cloned element doesn't seem to add enough benefit to justify the amount of JS that a complete duplicated solution would require. I'm curious, is there a reason it should be identical to WhatsApp?

Comment: I did not know of `position: sticky`! Interesting!

Comment: @Zeal I've got that from our UX designer and I should do it this way for our project but it's very complex :/ thats the problem I have. And I don't want to fail. I'm trying now the whole night to figure this out but thanks so much for your answer! I'll get you a thumbs up.

Comment: @Mr.Jo, okay. Fair enough. I posted another answer with a JS solution I worked up. I'm not sure about the security of your position on your team, but if I were in your place, I would make a case to the UX lead for sticking with CSS-only when the difference is this minor. By using JS, you'll be adding complexity and relying on a larger set of API implementations within the different browsers which may lead to some bugs.